# Firebase: Allow access depending on time difference (server-side-time)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, timestamp

So I have a database that looks like this:

```
Posts
|
|
|----post_id_1
     |
     |---post_title = "...."
     |---post_body = "...."
     |---post_time = "ServerValue.TIME_STAMP"
|
|----post_id_2
     |.......
     |.......
```

**What I want to do:**

I want to prevent a user to read a post that is greater than or equal a month from the day that it was posted?

**What I tried:**

I tried to use this method by android:

```
//current time of device
long current_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
//month in millisecond
long month = .....;

if(curent_time - post_time >= month){

//this post was there for a month from the time that it was posted.

}
```

**Problem:**

If I use the above method then if a user was smart enough he/she will change the time of the device to enter a post (when they shouldn't).

**Question:**

Any stable way of doing this?

Thanks.

**NOTE: WITHOUT GETTING THE TIME STAMP FROM THE SERVER.**

Comment: the timestamp from the server is your best choise in this case, if you want i can give you a few lines that i use in my code to store server time by google into firebase, i use it in order to make weekly backups for my users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been through the same issue, how I solved that was pinging Google for the time, and then just store that time in Firebase, that way I can compare the last time the user did something and that time will be server time and can't be changed.

So, in my case I upload that server time each time my app enters in the `onStop` or `onDestroy` method, but you can use it anywhere you need to save to your database.

Here is the snippet to get server time, I use an `asyncTask` in order to fetch the server time and then just post it in my reference. Just call the `asyncTask` where you want to update something with server time.

```
public class getGoogleTime extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet("https://google.com/"));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH);
                dateStr = response.getFirstHeader("Date").getValue();
                Date startDate = df.parse(dateStr);
                dateStr = String.valueOf(startDate.getTime() / 1000);
                long actualTime = java.lang.Long.parseLong(dateStr);
                //Here I do something with the Date String

            } else {
                //Closes the connection.
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("SAF_GTG_Response", e.getMessage());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    // can use UI thread here
    protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {

        mDatabase.child("Posts").child(post_id_1).child("currentTime").setValue(dateStr, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

                Log.d("SAF_GTG_TAG", "Success");

            }
        });


    }
}
```

To work with Firebase you can do this:

```
 ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();    

    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            Long timestamp = (Long) snapshot.getValue();
            System.out.println(timestamp);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    ref.setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```

NOTE: this method just returns UTC time, you can convert it the way you want to display it to each user.

If you are worried about network usage, just ping Google and see how many bytes and packages are being used.

```
Pinging google.com [172.217.162.14] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.217.162.14: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=53
Reply from 172.217.162.14: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=53
Reply from 172.217.162.14: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=53
Reply from 172.217.162.14: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=53

Ping statistics for 172.217.162.14:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 16ms, Maximum = 17ms, Average = 16ms
```

From the docs:

> The bandwidth consumption of a simple ping command, being run one time
>   per second, is relatively small. The smallest ping packet possible
>   (including the Ethernet frame header and the IP + ICMP headers, plus
>   the minimum 32 bytes of the ICMP payload) takes 74 bytes

around 0,074 kilobytes.

Comment: Thanks, but don't you think that running a function every time you need the current time a bit expensive?

Comment: it justs pings google, i think there is no waste of resources there to be worried about :) , also, to get server time you need to call it each time you want to work with it

Comment: Do you think it would be easier to store the `post_time` and `post_time_until_one_month` fields in my database?

Comment: you can make a constant lets say 30 days in miliseconds and then sum that with the post time, if the current user connection is higher than the post connection + 30 days in miliseconds , you are sure that it has been more than 30 days, also comparing with miliseconds can tell you that 30 days have passed after the first bit of the last number in the miliseconds date

Comment: You mean every time I post I add the`post_time` and and `post_time_plus_a_month_in_millisecond`. And just compare these values on client side?

Comment: yep, you store the currentTime of the user, that will be your last time, and then just get the post time, add to it 30 days in miliseconds and get that currentTime of the user and check, `if postTime + 30daysinmilis < currentTime`    30 days have passed

Comment: This means that when I need current time I always need to be connected?

Comment: there is no need to upload it to firebase, you can work with just the connection time that gives you the method i wrote above, but yes, since its servertime you will need to be connected

Comment: in the onPostExecute of this method, delete the setValue i did and just compare the time you got from google with the post time + 30 days and execute this whenever you want to check for that

Comment: But we could get the current time from firebase? Why didn't you do that instead?

Comment: of course, is the same, you can do that as well, i was just helping with what i have done to solve the problem

Comment: Yes I know thanks......but I mean why didn't you do that instead for your case I mean.....isn't it easier?

Comment: when i did the first block of code in the answer it was like a year back and i never touch it since it works fantastic each time , and at that time i didnt knew about ServerValue.TIMESTAMP

Comment: Ahh any way thanks for spending the time and for all the effort you put.

Comment: there is no problem, get to me anytime you need help :)

Answer (score 1):

I would store the TIME_STAMP as UTC and get the time from the server, not use the time from the device.

In that case the user cannot change the time on the device to modify the output from the database.

I would recommend to always store all dates as UTC and just convert them to the user timezone when the user views them.

Comment: So in my case what should I do?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the only thing you want to do is to compare if the current date is more than than the posted date plus a month. Store the posted date as UTC in the DB and compare to the current UTC date on the server.